# JSON parser doesn't work objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Some days ago I tryid to read and parse data from server. But today it doesn't work. What can be wrong?
Here I out my method:

```
 -(void) getDataFromServer
 {
     act = @"linkinginit";
     deviceid = @"1xyhgjs";
     fullRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://app.ivson.by/?act=%@&deviceid=%@",    act, deviceid];
    NSLog(@"%@", fullRequest);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullRequest];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: nil error: nil];


  NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [strData length]);
  NSLog(@"Data from server = %@", strData);
  NSString *json = strData;
    //   NSString *json = @"{\"code\":200,\"serviceID\":\"53d22b10e46a5\",\"sender\":1,\"hasPair\":0}";
   NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSError *error = nil;
   id obj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                         options:0
                                           error:&error];
if (obj) {
    NSAssert([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]], @"Expected a dictionary");
    NSDictionary *dictObj = (NSDictionary *)obj;
    NSNumber *code = dictObj[@"code"];
    NSLog(@"code:", code);
    NSString *serviceId = dictObj[@"serviceID"];
    NSLog(@"serviceId:", serviceId);
    NSNumber *sender = dictObj[@"sender"];
    NSLog(@"sender:",sender);
    NSNumber *hasPair = dictObj[@"hasPair"];
    NSLog(@"hasPair:", hasPair);

} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to parse JSON: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

}

And output is like this. I need to have all variables(code, serviceId, sender and hasPair) separate.

```
  2014-07-28 11:46:41.640 Nanny[1445:11303] http://app.ivson.by/?   act=linkinginit&deviceid=1xyhgjs
 2014-07-28 11:46:41.923 Nanny[1445:15b03] ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY: http://app.ivson.by/?act=linkinginit&deviceid=1xyhgjs
 2014-07-28 11:46:41.924 Nanny[1445:11303] Data from server = {"code":200,"serviceid":"53d60c7cc35f1","sender":1,"hasPair":0}
 2014-07-28 11:46:41.924 Nanny[1445:11303] code:
 2014-07-28 11:46:41.925 Nanny[1445:11303] serviceId:
 2014-07-28 11:46:41.925 Nanny[1445:11303] sender:
 2014-07-28 11:46:41.925 Nanny[1445:11303] hasPair:
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you converting data -> string -> data?

Comment: I'm new to Objective c. Is it easy way? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing to do with being new to Objective C. You have a method that gives you NSData. You have another method that wants NSData. So why do you convert NSData to NSString and back to NSData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in NSLog, you're not passing type of arguments. Try this

```
if (obj) {
    NSAssert([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]], @"Expected a dictionary");
    NSNumber *code = obj[@"code"];
    NSLog(@"code: %@", code);
    NSString *serviceId = obj[@"serviceID"];
    NSLog(@"serviceId: %@", serviceId);
    NSNumber *sender = obj[@"sender"];
    NSLog(@"sender: %@",sender);
    NSNumber *hasPair = obj[@"hasPair"];
    NSLog(@"hasPair: %@", hasPair);

} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to parse JSON: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Rather than "not passing type of arguments", OP doesn't use format string at all, just expecting NSLog to print string representations of all parameters.

Comment: No, it doesn't work with field serviceID:Data from server = {"code":200,"serviceid":"53d611eb0a6cb","sender":1,"hasPair":0}
2014-07-28 12:09:52.243 Nanny[1598:11303] code: 119505712
2014-07-28 12:09:52.244 Nanny[1598:11303] serviceId: (null)
2014-07-28 12:09:52.244 Nanny[1598:11303] sender: 119080880
2014-07-28 12:09:52.244 Nanny[1598:11303] hasPair: 119112448

Comment: just updated my answer check it.. It's working fine for all NSLog

Comment: It don't work too( Data from server = {"code":200,"serviceid":"53d614fd3b335","sender":1,"hasPair":0}
2014-07-28   code: 200
2014-07-28  serviceId: (null)
2014-07-28  sender: 1
2014-07-28  hasPair: 0

Comment: but on my side It's work fine, Just simply copy my code and replace on your matching code.. Because you are using "dictObj" and "dictObj" is empty dictionary .. Try my code .. I have tested this on xcode..

Comment: and your hasPair is also have 0 value .. so It's printing 0

Comment: Yes, see here http://imgur.com/tYeeKXq. Is it server mistake? It was working nice some days ago...

Comment: @Joge You have the wrong case with `serviceID` (should be `serviceid`).

Comment: @Joge Also why have you removed the casting of `obj` to `dictObj`?

Comment: why we need dicObj when we can do easily from obj

Comment: Oh, it's all of register. Smb changes input form "serverId" to "serverid"